# Writing scripts that work with my emails

Tags: email, thunderbird, python

I currently use Thunderbird as my email client and it has some filters, but that seems to be all I can program in it.

On several occasions, I heard people talk about their automated email workflow. One example:

> When I do not get a reply to an email the script will send a “nag” email asking why I did not get a response yet.

Or another one:

> I get so much mail that I cannot read them all. After a week, unread email is put on hold and the sender gets a “if it was important, reply to this email and it will be set to un-hold” email. The script then takes the answer and move it to back into the *important* folder.

I read about [FiltaQuilla](http://mesquilla.com/extensions/filtaquilla/) which seems nice, but it does not seem to be the kind of programming that I am looking for.

How can I write general purpose scripts like those? Do I need to write my own Python IMAP/SMTP client (if that is even possible) to to this or can I script it it, say JavaScript, in Thunderbird?

Comment: Maybe relevant: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_(mail_filtering_language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_(mail_filtering_language))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to look at the StackOverflow question [Thunderbird Scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096187/thunderbird-scripting), which appears to cover much the same problem.  The solution suggested there is to write your own plugin.

Alternatively, there's a plugin called [tbscript](http://code.google.com/p/tbscript-plugin/) (which I haven't tried, so no promises), which might do what you're after, although it does have external dependencies (Python and PyXPCOMExt)